# How do I get the metadata of a file after uploading it to firestore as a return value to the function, given that the upload process is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

New to Js and looking to work around something I am doing perharps someone can help…
I am uploading a file to firebase storage. It is by nature async process. but I also need the function to return the metadata for the file when the async uploading is done. I can't achieve this directly because the return will come to me even before the file starts uploading.

What I want is to wait for the upload to finish and if successful, the overall function should return its promise. Note I know how to extract the metadata the problem is more about how to make the asynchronous function return a value it is going to get in the future

my function looks like this…

```
   const uploadFile = (file, directory)=>{
   prepare the file and create ref
   create an upload task called uploadTask with a put method
   //now I can wait for its promise as follows
   uploadTask.then( (promiseValue ={
   // I want to return this promiseValue in the uploadFile function
 })
   // This is where I want to return it promiseValue
}
```

In the end what I want is that if I call uploadFile like below:

```
const metaData = uploadFile(someFile, itsDirectory)
```

I want metaData to hold the value of promiseValue

I have tried to return the value in the then method but it doesnt work. if Try to return outside of the then method, in the main function, I get undefined, which is understandable to me because at the time of returning, the upload process is underway and the promise is not ready yet. But If I console log it works.

Answer (score 1):

`then` returns a promise that resolves whenever its work is complete.  Just return it from the function.  The caller can use it to determine when everything is done.

```
return uploadTask.then(result => ...)
```

It is very common in JavaScript to chain promises like this with a series of `then` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the the tips and for editing my question... I find it difficult to post properly on SO

Comment: I tried this approach, But I had what looks weird as an output. the return value was an object looking like this:  `{ [[promiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[promiseValue]]: {object containing exactly the results I want}`  The problem is I can't extract them because the way it is presented. I guess I don't know how to deal with that kind of object with a double array as the keys